# Solving a First Order Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking at the following problem. I'm trying to solve for y, and separating variables doesn't look like an option. I'm thinking putting it into standard form of a first order linear eq would be a good place to start. Is this correct?

$$ \frac{y' - e^{-t} +3}{y} = -3 $$
$$ y(0) = 5 $$

In standard form:
$$ y' + P(x)y = Q(x) $$
$$ y' + 3y = -3 + e^{-t} $$

$$ ye^{3t} = \int{-3e^{3t} + e^{2t}*dt} $$
$$ ye^{3t} = e^{-3t} + 0.5e^{2t} + C $$
$$ y = -1 + 0.5e^{-t} + C $$

Solving for initial condition y(0) = 5:
$$ y=-1+0.5e^{-t} + C $$
$$ y(0) = -1+0.5e^{0} + C = 5 $$
$$ y(0) = -0.5 + C = 5 $$
$$ y(0) = C = 5.5 $$

Plug back in C:
$$ y=-1+0.5e^{-t}+5.5 $$

I've went through the steps of calculating the integrating factor and solving for y. The answer was incorrect. Is this the right way to approach this problem?

Comment: Can you add your extra work?

Comment: I have added the extra work.

Comment: ye3t=∫−3e3t+e2t∗dt <<< Why are you doing this?

Comment: Your integration factor, e^3, is wrong.

Comment: I've used an integration factor of e^{3t} -- I believe that was an error in formatting.

Comment: @Jossie I learned that he integral of the left hand side is equal to Y*I (where I is the ingratiation factor). This is assuming that it is in standard form and the integration factor was calculated properly. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{y' - e^{-t} +3}{y} = -3 \Longrightarrow y' - e^{-t} = -3y - 3 \Longrightarrow y' + 3y = -3 + e^{-t}$$

As you can see, when you have the first-order linear ODE, $$y' + a(t)y = b(t)$$
So in this case, 3 = a(t). So $e^{\int 3 dt} = e^{3t}$. 
$$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{3t}y) = -3 + e^{-t}$$

Now integrate both sides AND DO NOT FORGET THE CONSTANT.

$$e^{3t}y + C = -3t - e^{-t}$$

Isolate $y$. The end.

Comment: I have gotten here without issue, but then solved for y(0)=5 and then got a wrong answer. I have put my work up in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both sides by $e^{3t}$. Recognize $(ye^{3t})'$. Integrate.